# "Stressful to" vs. "stressful for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

Which preposition, *for* or *to*, is correct in below sentence?

> It is less stressful [for/to] a child than an adult to learn a foreign language.

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the answers, *for* is definitely the right preposition here.

Comment: Related: [Rule for using “for” vs. “to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/rule-for-using-for-vs-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preposition *for* introduces the person who feels stressful, regardless of the verb form used:

> Working is stressful *for* some.
>
> It is stressful *for* some to work.

You can omit the subject of the stress:

> It is stressful to work.

[NGrams shows](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=stressful+to+me%2Cstressful+for+me&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that *to* is also used but *for* is the preferred preposition.  It also shows that stress was popularised in the late 20th century.

[image]

Comment: You said the same I did: use of "for" as the basic one, and "to" with verbs. What's the difference?

Comment: I am saying the object person is always introduced with _for_, never _to_.  In the examples _to_ is not a preposition it is part of a verb form.  The verb form that describes the action causing the stress.

Comment: Ok but I never said "to" is a preposition... Plus it seems czh found an entry where to is used as a preposition.

Comment: Yes.. it seems that it's in use, but for is preferred

Comment: I agree on that.

Comment: Judging from the hits google gets, some of these cites of "stressful to me" in the Ngram are probably sentences like *"Your job seems very stressful to me,"* while others are cases of people using *to* rather than *for* that I would consider incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> It is less stressful ( for / to ) a child than an adult to learn a foreign language.

"For" is the right choice, but it would be even better as:

It is less stressful for a child to learn a foreign language than for an adult.